# Dealing with log4j vulnerability in FME products

Tags: fme-form, security, fme-flow

Is there a way to mitigate any risk associated with the log4j vulnerability in FME Products?

- FME Desktop
- FME Server
- FME License Server (FlexLM)

Answer (score 4):

At the time of writing, Safe Software have written a [**blog**](https://community.safe.com/s/article/Is-FME-Server-Affected-by-the-Security-Vulnerability-Reported-Against-log4j) about the impacts of the log4j vulnerability in FME Desktop, FME Server and the FME License Server software.

The blog states that Safe do not have concerns about the vulnerability, however, they recommend that users upgrade to the newest version of FME when it becomes available.

> Only FME versions 2021.0 and newer contain the vulnerable versions of log4j, so FME 2020.2 and older do not need to be updated as they do not contain a version of log4j that is included in the vulnerability.

Further, if users wanted to upgrade, Safe provided instructions for updating the log4j files used by FME Server and FME Desktop. FME License Server is not affected.